# IE 7 z-index, overlap div in another stack

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

```
<pre><code>    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
    <style>
.back{width: 1000px;height: 1000px;z-index: 1;position: fixed;top: 0px;
left:0px;opacity: 0.5;filter: alpha(opacity=50);background-color: Black;}

#main
{margin: 100px 0 0 100px;width: 500px;position: absolute;background-color: Aqua;}

#div1 {background-color: yellow;z-index:2;position: relative;}
#div2 {background-color: yellowgreen;}
#div3 {position: relative;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="div1">
            <div>
                <input value="0000" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="div2">
            <div>
                <input value="1111" />
            </div>
            <div class="back">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="div3">
        <input value="222" />
    </div>
</body>
```

Hi all, i need overlap all with div class='back' except div2, but IE7 show div3 too. It should look like popup. Alternative is to clone div2 and append it to body, but i dont like this idea.

Comment: did you try to add to div3 z-index lower than your popup? If div2 is displayed corretly then just remove "position: relative" from div3 and it should work too I guess

Comment: i can change only div2 or add other divs anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [z-index bug in IE7](http://therealcrisp.xs4all.nl/meuk/IE-zindexbug.html) when using relatively positioned elements. There's a [non-JS solution](http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/) you can try (Not easy though because of the makup), but there's also an easy JS solution for that.

You can see a working example in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LN67V/1/).

The jQuery function goes like this:

```
if (document.all && !window.opera && window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    $(function() {
        var zIndexNumber = 1000;
        $('div,p,li').each(function() {
            $(this).css('zIndex', zIndexNumber);
            zIndexNumber -= 10;
        });
    });
}
```

It checks if you are on IE (You could just call the script using [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)), and if so, it loops through the divs setting a lower z-index each loop.

Now your input box is behind .back in IE7.